# Savon: set SSL ciphers list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, curl, savon, curb

I recently upgraded to OS X El Capitan, and now I'm getting the error `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: dh key too small`. I know this is because the server is using an insecure Diffie Hellman key, but I can't change anything about the server.

If I use Homebrew's curl version and do `curl --cipher 'DEFAULT:!DH' https://my.site.com`, it does work. So, I'm almost positive it has something to do with the key.

Is there any way to get around this? Can I set it so curl or Savon let me use an insecure key?

Answer (score 2):

Savon uses the [HTTPi library](http://httpirb.com/) for the network requests but this library **does not support setting SSL ciphers**, as can be seen from the list of [SSL options in the documentation](http://httpirb.com/#authentication).

From the question tags I suppose that you use [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) as the network adapter for Savon/HTTPi and Curb luckily supports setting various SSL options, including the allowed ciphers list through the general [`set` method](https://github.com/taf2/curb/blob/master/lib/curl/easy.rb#L33) on the curl client.

So I guess your only option is to monkey-patch HTTPi to set the appropriate cipher when calling setting up the Curb client. A cleaner approach would be to also monkey patch Savon to pass a "ssl_ciphers" option to the HTTPi library but I'll leave that as an exercise for you if you want it :).

The most straightforward place to patch is the [`setup_ssl_auth` method](https://github.com/savonrb/httpi/blob/master/lib/httpi/adapter/curb.rb#L103) in the `curb` adapter of HTTPi. The following patch redefines this method to also **explicitly deny the `DH` ciphers in the list of allowed SSL ciphers**:

```
module HTTPI
  module Adapter
    class Curb

      alias_method :orig_setup_ssl_auth, :setup_ssl_auth

      private 
      def setup_ssl_auth
        orig_setup_ssl_auth
        @client.set(:SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "DEFAULT:!DH")
      end

    end
  end
end
```

The patch calls the original `set_ssl_auth` method first and then denies the `DH` ciphers on the client. Note that this patch denies the `DH` ciphers everywhere Savon / HTTPi is used in your application!

Further notes on setting SSL ciphers can be found [in the libcurl docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST.html).